# How to join any class to view mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

is there any way to attach any class to the view? I would like to attach a different class to one view each time. I mean something like that:

```
public PartialViewResult Filtres()
    {
          return PartialView(Processors);
    }

@model typeof(class)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. First of all, you do not "attach" a class to a view.

A view is built on top of a model. The reason is simple, so it can actually display something otherwise why would it even exist?

I suppose you could, in theory have something generic like object for example, but that would not get you very far, because you'd have to cast that generic object to something you can actually work with, the real underlying type.

This also means your view would be littered with if statements, which is a really bad way of building anything.

Stick to how these things are supposed to work I'd say. If you need multiple classes, then create one view per class and all common bits can be done as Partial Views.

Comment: I solved this problem by passing the class as an object

Comment: yes, i mentioned the same thing, but that in itself creates an issue, already explained in my answer

Comment: I understand the problem you rescribe but I only need this for a partial view which I only use for a form. Thaks for a help